# Create a new object using keys and values from another object

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, key-value

I'm saving an object in state that looks like:

```
ingredients: {
        salad: {
            amount: 3,
            basePrice: 1
        },
        cheese: {
            amount: 2,
            basePrice: 1.2
        }
}
```

I want to use this in my component's state as follows

```
    ingredients: {
    salad: 3,
    cheese: 2
}
```

I used `Object.keys` and `map` at first but it returns an Array of key value pairs instead of objects.

Although this works:

```js
    const newIngredientsObject = {};
    for (const i in ingredientsObject)
        newIngredientsObject[i] = ingredientsObject[i].amount;
        return newIngredientsObject;
```

I want to find a solution without a helper method, as such:

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ingredients: Object.keys(state.burger.ingredients).map(i => (
            { [i]: state.burger.ingredients[i].amount } )),
        totalPrice: state.burger.totalPrice
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the entries of the object by using the `amount` property of the values and take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for getting a new object.

```js
var ingredients = { salad: { amount: 3, basePrice: 1 }, cheese: { amount: 2, basePrice: 1.2 } },
    result = Object.assign(
        ...Object.entries(ingredients).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value.amount }))
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to create one object to inside to another go this web

```
object 1  = {
content 1 = {
    stuff = {
    },
    more Stuff = {
    }
}
```

}
object 2 = {
    key 1:"",
key 2:""

}
object 1.content 1 = object 2;

Answer (score 0):

You asked a solution with Object.keys, here is one:

```
var x = {ingredients: {
        salad: {
            amount: 3,
            basePrice: 1
        },
        cheese: {
            amount: 2,
            basePrice: 1.2
        }
}}

Object.keys(x.ingredients).map((d,i)=>[d,x.ingredients[d].amount]).reduce((ac,d,i)=>(ac[d[0]]=d[1],ac),{})

//{salad: 3, cheese: 2}
```

Comment: would you mind explaining why the ", ac" is there in this return?:

`(ac[d[0]]=d[1],ac)`

Comment: in reduce, at each iteration you have to return the accumulator. I did not want to write 2 separate lines, so what I did is enclose 2 statements in paranth. If you do that, paranth returns the last statement/expression which is ac itself. It is a bad habbit, if you work w/ teams, your pull requests will be rejected, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest I could come up with it using `Object.keys` and `reduce`

```js
const ingredients = {
  salad: {
    amount: 3,
    basePrice: 1
  },
  cheese: {
    amount: 2,
    basePrice: 1.2
  }
};

let newObject = Object.keys(ingredients).reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val] = ingredients[val].amount;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**:
Thanks for the solutions provided by [@ibowankenobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9410412/ibowankenobi) and [@Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz)

- *Reduce function:*

```js
Object.keys(ingredients)
    .map( (d, i) => [d, ingredients[d].amount])
    .reduce( (ac, d, i) => (ac[d[0]] = d[1], ac), {} );
```

- *Entries function:*

```js
Object.assign(...Object.entries(ingredients)
    .map( ([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value.amount }) ) );
```

```
reduce: 0.0849609375ms
entries: 0.1650390625ms
forLoop: 0.07421875ms
reduce: 0.024169921875ms
entries: 0.048095703125ms
forLoop: 0.010009765625ms
reduce: 0.010009765625ms
entries: 0.016845703125ms
forLoop: 0.0078125ms
```

After some testing, it seems like using a for loop is the most efficient and after that the reduce function.